# Getting Invalid certificate error on bundle with heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, bundler

I have a private gem repository hosted in the cloud and accessible via https. The certificates are valid and signed.

The problem is when deploying an app that uses this private repo to Heroku, I'm getting this output:

```
Retrying source fetch due to error (2/3): Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureError Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://mygemserver.com/.
  There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For information about OpenSSL certificates, see bit.ly/ruby-ssl. To connect without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.
  Retrying source fetch due to error (3/3): Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureError Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://mygemserver.com/.
  There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For information about OpenSSL certificates, see bit.ly/ruby-ssl. To connect without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.
  Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://mygemserver.com/.
  There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most
  likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For
  information about OpenSSL certificates, see bit.ly/ruby-ssl. To connect without
  using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.
  Bundler Output: Fetching source index from https://mygemserver.com/
  Retrying source fetch due to error (2/3): Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureError Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://mygemserver.com/.
  There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For information about OpenSSL certificates, see bit.ly/ruby-ssl. To connect without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.
  Retrying source fetch due to error (3/3): Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureError Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://mygemserver.com/.
  There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For information about OpenSSL certificates, see bit.ly/ruby-ssl. To connect without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.
  Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://mygemserver.com/.
  There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most
  likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For
  information about OpenSSL certificates, see bit.ly/ruby-ssl. To connect without
  using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.
  !
  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
  !

  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

It looks like it is not able to validate the certificates. I got the same problem on my local and was able to fix by running 'rvm osx-ssl-certs update'. This command updates the certificates bundle recognised by the system. How can I reproduce this behaviour in Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that we were able to fix this by appending an intermediate certificate, provided by comodo, to the certificate itself.